# How to replace ViewController.xib with a new made Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, viewcontroller, xcode5.1

Can somebody tell me how to replace my ViewController.xib with a newly created storyboard. My project doesn't have a storyboard, it starts from ViewController.xib.

Comment: in the .plist you declare the name of your storyboard as a string under the "Main storyboard file base name (<device>)" key.

Comment: @ ryancumley
Hello I tried it and it gives me error saying "Could not load NIB in bundle:"

Comment: Create a brand new "single view" application, and use it as an example. It will be pre-configured to launch from a storyboard. Also, don't forget to remove the reference to the .xib file in your code, now that you are launching from a storyboard.